# Nav element won't fully float to the right

Tags: css, html, css-float

```css
/* Generic Styles */
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #222222;
    font: 1em;
}

.container {
 margin: auto;
 width: 90%;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* Layout Styles */
header {
 background-image: url(../images/rocket.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: left;
 background-color: #003151;
}

header img {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

header h3 {
 clear: both;
}

nav {
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 1.250em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 62px;
 }

nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 04%;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" title="Home page"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Home page" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio" title="See some of my featured work">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="services" title="Learn more about my services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="about" title="Learn more about me">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog" title="View latest posts">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="faqs" title="View latest FAQS">FAQS</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact" title="Get in touch">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <h3>BlahBlahBlahH3</h3>

    <p>BlahBlahBlah</p>

    <a href="#" class="btn" title="Get in touch">Get in touch</a>

  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->

</header>
<!-- End Header -->
```

Despite my best efforts it's as if the `nav` element has some kind of padding or margin (which it doesn't). If I set the width to 100% to stop the `nav` spilling onto two lines it then jumps beneath the logo instead of floating to the right on the same line as the logo. The code may be a little messy now from a lot of trial and error but can anyone explain why if I don't set the `nav` element to width 100% that the `nav` spills onto two lines or why if it is set to 100% it won't stay floated to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyo,

It looks like your % margin is flubbing things up. If you're willing to part ways with that (suggested if you're going to be in such tight spaces where 4% will be very tiny), try this:

```
nav {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Your nav is rather large, so at around the 900px breakpoint, you'll want to either reduce the font-size, or shift it all to float:left, so that when it goes below the logo it looks more natural.

Comment: Strangely this seems to be right - I can have a far bigger margin using px than % without it breaking onto two lines. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Percent margins can be funky when you don't define widths and have floating elements all the way through. Those elements' widths are calculated on the fly, and don't account for the %-margin (since it need to know the widths before it can be a number). This makes for unpredictable layouts. Try giving your logo a 10%, nav a 90% width, and then your UL a width of 100%. That allows your containers to be defined without relying on the calculation of the floating elements' widths. It will avoid the irregular wrapping.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `width: 100%` from your `nav`.
2. Remove `padding` and `margin` from `ul` (added by browser as default)
3. Reduce `font-size` of `nav` items - if its too big of course the `nav` will wrap!
4. Note that your `container` has `width` of 90% - as the `nav` is within this, it won't reach the far right edge.

```css
/* Generic Styles */

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #222222;
  font: 1em;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Layout Styles */

header {
  background-image: url(../images/rocket.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left;
  background-color: #003151;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

header h3 {
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 62px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 14px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" title="Home page"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Home page" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio" title="See some of my featured work">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="services" title="Learn more about my services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="about" title="Learn more about me">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog" title="View latest posts">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="faqs" title="View latest FAQS">FAQS</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact" title="Get in touch">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <h3>BlahBlahBlahH3</h3>

    <p>BlahBlahBlah</p>

    <a href="#" class="btn" title="Get in touch">Get in touch</a>

  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->

</header>
<!-- End Header -->
```

Comment: 1. Already tried this. 2. Already done this. 3. I'm well aware of that but the nav should easily fit at the current font size. 4. Correct. The nav wont float right up against the edge of the container. I know it won't float outside of it's container.